# SQL Query With Three Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I need help building a SQL query that returns results from three different tables. I have successfully created statements for two tables, but can't get all three.

The tables and relevant fields are as follows:

```
Order        OrderItem       Product
-------      -----------     -----------
orderId      orderId         productCode
status       productCode     productName
             quantity
```

I'm looking for the desired result set:

```
[productCode]    [productName]    [orderCount]
-------------    -----------      ----------
123              widget           3
456              thing            2
```

The results would be grouped by `productCode` from `OrderItem`, with the `productName` from `Product`, and the number of times the product has been ordered and shipped.

The shipping status comes from the `status` field on `Order`. i.e. only include `OrderItem` rows where the `status` field on the `Order` is "shipped".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: The process is pretty much the same as joining two tables. The first join creates a secondary table, which can then be joined to the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    c.productCode,
    c.productName,
    COUNT(*) orderCount
FROM Order a
INNER JOIN OrderItem b
ON a.orderId = b.orderId
INNER JOIN Product c
ON b.productCode = c.productCode
WHERE status = 'shipped'
GROUP BY
    c.productCode,
    c.productName
```

Comment: this works great, I need to sum the quantities rather than just count the orders, but the joins work great. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    p.productCode, p.productName, count(o.OrderId) as orderCount,
    sum(oi.quantity) as orderQuantity -- Optional (if you want the sum of products ordered)
from
    [product] as p
    inner join [orderItem] as oi on p.productCode = oi.productcode
    inner join [order] as o on oi.orderId = o.orderId
group by 
    p.productCode, p.productName
```

Comment: this works, but it shows all orders regardless of shipping status, but it's easily fixed with a WHERE clause.